# Array with some null field in where clause not working in Codeigniter Activerecord

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to run this query passing `$data` array in where clause.But in this `$data` array one or more field value can be null and some fields are not as look like below:

```
$data = Array(
 [c.client_id]=>
 [c.conn_type]=>
 [c.pkg_id]=> 2
 [c.area_id]=> 1
 [c.managed_by]=> 3
 [c.status]=>
)

function getAllClientByParam($data){
        $this->db->select('c.client_id, c.client_name, c.conn_charge, c.con_date, cd.disconnect, c.mobile, p.pkg_name, ct.conn_type, s.status, a.area, m.managed_by, c.remarks');
        $this->db->from('bill_client AS c');
        $this->db->join('bill_connection_details AS cd','c.client_id=cd.client_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('bill_pkg AS p','c.pkg_id=p.pkg_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('bill_connection_type AS ct','c.conn_type=ct.conn_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('bill_conn_status AS s','c.status=s.id','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('bill_area AS a','c.area_id=a.area_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('bill_managed_by AS m','c.managed_by=m.managed_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->where('c.company_id', $this->company_id);
        $this->db->where($data);

        $client_list = $this->db->get();
        $data = $client_list->result();
        return $data;
}
```

How do I retrieve all data with this query according to `$data` variable in where clause?

Answer (score 0):

In your example $data it would always have to contain entries that actually have values... so you example $data would need to be...

```
    $data = array(
        'c . pkg_id'      => 2,
        'c . area_id '    => 1,
        'c . managed_by' => 3
    );
```

So you would need to build your $data array before passing it into your method.